# Interesting Uses of STL Algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I apologize because I know in advance this question may be closed. I know it is not an essentially technical question, but it is one that could be meaningfully answered by experienced c++ programmers.

I am teaching a C++ class for programming students and, naturally, I will be covering the STL algorithms. I was trying to think of examples I could give in lecture that would be really cool applications of STL algorithms that make fairly complicated code really simple. I know some people here have ridiculously more C++ experience than I do so I was wondering if you could think of some interesting/exciting applications of the STL algorithms that could be done via loops and functions, but are really easy and concise using the stl algorithms.

Some of my examples:

1. **Check if palindrome**: Made really easy with `equals(s.begin(), s.begin() + v.size()/2, s.rbegin())`
2. **Tokenize string into vector**: Easy with `copy(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<>(), back_inserter(data))`
3. **Permutations**: Classic recursive problem made easy by stl algorithms
4. **Sorting**: This one is obvious but also not very interesting (i.e. it's not a cool application of `<algorithm>` for students)

Comment: There are probably other SE sites that are a better fit for questions like this. I suggest you look around a little bit.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Like what? Academia? Mathematics Educators? I couldn't seem to find one but I would love a suggestion.

Comment: I like neat implementation of algorithms in modern c++, but this one is too broad, and opinion-based. You can come up with plethora of algorithms and argue which are interesting and which are not =/. One thing that might yield some results, look at top answers with tags [c++] and [algorithm]. Also high rep users with golden badges in c++ often have few interesting answers.

Comment: Programmers.SE appears to allow broader questions than SO, but I'm not really active outside of SO, so I'm afraid you'll have to read through a couple of help pages yourself or ask on meta.SE or something like that.

Comment: Well, your palindrome checking works only if you remember to erase spaces and special characters before using it, otherwise "Was it a car or a cat I saw?" won't be accepted. Btw sorting wrom STL will be pretty interesting for lazy ones. ;)

Comment: @luk32 Your point is valid, and I was hesitant to ask for this very reason. I tried to steer away from asking the "most" interesting so they did not have to be ranked in any such order, but it is hard for this not to be opinion based.

Comment: @KamilKoczurek Naturally :) Just wanted to fit the point on one line here.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: No, it's not. That cannot be interpreted as a function declaration (or an object declaration, for that matter).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Nvm, I was confused. Thx.